# When is a python module a package?

Tags: python-3.x, module, package, python-import

[The official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-package) says

> __package__ :
> The module’s __package__ attribute must be set. Its value must be a string, but it can be the same value as its __name__. When the module is a package, its __package__ value should be set to its __name__. **When the module is not a package**, __package__ should be set to the empty string for top-level modules, or for submodules, to the parent package’s name. See PEP 366 for further details.

Is not a module a python file and a package a directory that contains these modules. There could be nested, hierarchical subpakcages and modules within them. But, what does the official documentation mean when it says "**when the module is not a package**". When is a module a package? The two seem like apples and oranges to me. If I am missing some fundamental way the modules and packages are defined then please refer me to some resources as well that can clear these out for me

Comment: The link in the question explains it quite well. A module is anything that can be `import`ed. A package is a module, that has the `__path__` attribute - which usually refers to a directory of sub-modules.

Comment: About that: When I read up on \_\_path\_\_ it says: If the module is a package (either regular or namespace), the module object’s \_\_path\_\_ attribute must be set. And when I try to understand what a package is it says "anything that has a \_\_path\_\_ attribute". This seems cyclic to me and I still don't understand it enough to say that if I do "import X" now my "X" would or would not have a "\_\_path\_\_" attribute. Can you please explain to me when should i expect to find a \_\_path\_\_ attribute present in anything that I import?

Comment: Take a look at [Python Modules and Packages – An Introduction](https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/) for a more in depth discussion of module vs package differences.